# Writing unit tests with DB connections/drivers with nodeunit

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, nodeunit

I am trying to write a set of test units for my simple DB layer [SimpleDbLayer](https://github.com/mercmobily/simpledblayer) **using [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit)**. I am finding it rather difficult.

Problems:

1) I want to connect to the DB once, and use that connection. I cannot really use setUp and tearDown, as they are run before and after *each* test. As a "solution", I am using a module-wide variable for the scope (see code below)

2) My simple DB layer has several DB drivers. MongoMixin is only one of them -- I have under development MariaMixin and PostgresMixin. Ideally I would run these tests one for each driver, to see if they work. Is there a good, easy way to do this?

3) I am hitting cases where I make a mistake with the code of my test, and all I get is a complaint about test.done not being detected. Is there any trickery I need to be aware of here?

4) Am I doing anything horribly wrong? (see code)

```
var 
  dummy

, declare = require('simpledeclare')
, SimpleDbLayer = require('./SimpleDbLayer')

, MongoMixin = require('./MongoMixin.js')

, mw = require('mongowrapper')
, async = require('async')
;

var db, layer;


exports.createLayer = {

  databaseConnect: function( test ){
    mw.connect('mongodb://localhost/hotplate', {}, function( err, returnedDb ){
      test.ifError( err );
      db = returnedDb;
      test.done( null );
    });
  },


  makeLayer: function( test ){

    var C = declare( [ SimpleDbLayer, MongoMixin ] );
    layer = new C( 'test', {  name: true, surname: true, age: true }, db );

    test.ok( layer );
    test.done(); 
  },

  deleteAll: function( test ){
    layer.delete( { }, { multi: true }, function( err, howmany ){
      test.ifError( err );
      test.done();
    });
  },

  insert: function( test ){
    var people = [
      { name: 'Chiara',    surname: 'Mobily',     age: 24 },
      { name: 'Tony',      surname: 'Mobily',     age: 37 },
      { name: 'Sara',      surname: 'Connor',     age: 14 },
      { name: 'Daniela',   surname: 'Mobily',     age: 64 },
    ];

    returnedPeople = [];

    var functions = [];

    // Populate the database
    people.forEach( function( person ){

      functions.push( function( done ){
        layer.insert( person, { returnRecord: true }, function( err, person ){
          test.ifError( err );
          returnedPeople.push( person );
          done( null );
        })
      })

    })

    async.series( functions, function( err, res ){
      test.ifError( err );
      test.done();
    });

  },

  databaseDisconnect: function( test ){
    db.close();
    test.done();
  },

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself.
The solution is simple: for each driver, this is the test.js file:

var driver = require('./specificDriver');
   var simpledblayerTests = require( "./lib/simpledblayer/test.js" );

```
var tests = simpledblayerTests.get(

  function getDbInfo( done ) {
    mw.connect('mongodb://localhost/tests', {}, function( err, db ){
      if( err ){
        throw new Error("MongoDB connect: could not connect to database");
      } else {
        done( null, db, driver );
      }
    });
  },

  function closeDb( db, done ) {
    db.close( done );
  }
);


for(var test in tests) {
    exports[ test ] = tests[ test ];
}
```

Basically, the `get()` function exported by the actual "main" module (more about this later) takes two parameters: two functions that open and close the database connection.

That `get()` function returns a bunch of functions ready to be exported -- the functions that make up your unit testings.

The main module will have something like this:

```
exports.get = function( getDbInfo, closeDb ){

  var tests;
  var g = {};

  var startup = function( test ){
    var self = this;

    test.doesNotThrow( function(){

      getDbInfo( function( err, db, driver ){
        if( err ){
          throw( new Error("Could not connect to db, aborting all tests") );
          process.exit();
        }

        // Set the important g.driver variables (db and driver)
        g.db = db;
        d.driver = driver

        test.done();
      });
    });
  }


  var finish = function( test ){
    var self = this;
    closeDb( g.db, function( err ){
      if( err ){
        throw( new Error("There was a problem disconnecting to the DB") );
      }
      test.done();
    });
  };

  tests = {

    startup: startup,

    // ...
    // Your tests here. All functions will have access to g.db and g.driver 
    // ...

    finish: finish

  }

  return tests;
}
```

This way, every single module will run the same tests. However, the `driver` variable and the functions to connect/disconnect to the database will be simple.

See it in action with real code:

- https://github.com/mercmobily/simpledblayer
- https://github.com/mercmobily/simpledblayer-mongo